# sinatra before/after filter inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance, filter, sinatra, block

Hy!

I have a Sinatra App:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base

  before do

    puts "do something..."

  end

end
```

---

```
class OneController < App

  before do

    super() # Not work

    puts "do something(App before filter) + more..."

  end

end
```

[Sinatra before filter](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters)

So e.g. in the **OneController** i need to run **App before block** and **OneController before block** too.
Please help! How do I do that?

The *super* keyword not work.

> NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `before (?-mix:)'

**Thanks!**
(Sorry for poor english)

Comment: I think that `before` is additive - you don't need to call `super`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `super` - `before` is additive - each time you call it you add to the previous calls:

```
class OneController < App

  before do
    puts "do something(App before filter) + more..."
  end

end
```